# Can I COUNTIF across multiple columns in an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Seems simple to me..

I want to do something along the lines of =Countif(A2:X , "Yes")

I would wrap this in an arrayformula with a simple IF(A2:A = "" ,"" .....

I want it to bring back the number of "Yes" per row

So if row 2 has 12 yes' then bring back 12, row 3 has 7 so 7 etc

This has worked to an extent but brings back the count across the entire range rather than split by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMult(N(A2:X="Yes"),Sequence(Columns(A2:X))^0)))
```

Or

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,Len(RegexReplace(RegexReplace(Transpose(Query(Transpose(A2:X),,9^9)),"(?i)\bYes\b","~"),"[^~]",))))
```

Or

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,Len(Substitute(Transpose(Query(Transpose(IF(A2:X<>"Yes",,"~")),,9^9))," ",))))
```

**Update**

> If I wanted to ammend this formula to do if A2:X = No AND A1:X1 contains, for instance (AG) how would I do this?

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMult((A2:X="No")*RegexMatch(A1:X1,"AG"),Sequence(Columns(A2:X))^0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a bit tedious, couldn't you do this:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A, "Yes") + COUNTIF(B2:B, "Yes") + COUNTIF(C2:C, "Yes") + COUNTIF(D2:D, "Yes") + COUNTIF(E2:E, "Yes") + COUNTIF(F2:F, "Yes") + COUNTIF(G2:G, "Yes") + COUNTIF(H2:H, "Yes") + COUNTIF(I2:I, "Yes") + COUNTIF(J2:J, "Yes") + COUNTIF(K2:K, "Yes") + COUNTIF(L2:L, "Yes") + COUNTIF(M2:M, "Yes") + COUNTIF(N2:N, "Yes") + COUNTIF(O2:O, "Yes") + COUNTIF(P2:P, "Yes") + COUNTIF(Q2:Q, "Yes") + COUNTIF(R2:R, "Yes") + COUNTIF(S2:S, "Yes") + COUNTIF(T2:T, "Yes") + COUNTIF(U2:U, "Yes") + COUNTIF(V2:V, "Yes") + COUNTIF(W2:W, "Yes") + COUNTIF(X2:X, "Yes")
```